# Change Twitter page feed to my own twitter

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-bootstrap

I bought a WrapBootstrap theme a few weeks ago and I'm trying to figure out how to change the twitter feed from the creators to my own.  I've posted the twitter.js file. Would the username be posted somewhere else?

```
function tz_format_twitter(twitters) {
  var statusHTML = [];
  for (var i=0; i<twitters.length; i++){
    var username = twitters[i].user.screen_name;
    var status = twitters[i].text.replace(/((https?|s?ftp|ssh)\:\/\/[^"\s\<\>]*    [^.,;'">\:\s\<\>\)\]\!])/g, function(url) {
      return '<a href="'+url+'">'+url+'</a>';
    }).replace(/\B@([_a-z0-9]+)/ig, function(reply) {
      return  reply.charAt(0)+'<a     href="http://twitter.com/'+reply.substring(1)+'">'+reply.substring(1)+'</a>';
    });
    statusHTML.push('<li><span>'+status+'</span> <br/><b><a     href="http://twitter.com/'+username+'/statuses/'+twitters[i].id_str+'">'+relative_time(twitter    s[i].created_at)+'</a></b></li>');
  }
  return statusHTML.join('');
}

function relative_time(time_value) {
  var values = time_value.split(" ");
  time_value = values[1] + " " + values[2] + ", " + values[5] + " " + values[3];
  var parsed_date = Date.parse(time_value);
  var relative_to = (arguments.length > 1) ? arguments[1] : new Date();
  var delta = parseInt((relative_to.getTime() - parsed_date) / 1000);
  delta = delta + (relative_to.getTimezoneOffset() * 60);

  if (delta < 60) {
    return 'less than a minute ago';
  } else if(delta < 120) {
    return 'about a minute ago';
  } else if(delta < (60*60)) {
    return (parseInt(delta / 60)).toString() + ' minutes ago';
  } else if(delta < (120*60)) {
    return 'about an hour ago';
  } else if(delta < (24*60*60)) {
    return 'about ' + (parseInt(delta / 3600)).toString() + ' hours ago';
  } else if(delta < (48*60*60)) {
    return '1 day ago';
  } else {
    return (parseInt(delta / 86400)).toString() + ' days ago';
  }
}
```

Comment: That sort of thing is usually in a configuration file, not in the JS.

Answer (score 0):

Found it in the custom.js file